# What is the duration of the temporary hit points granted by the Fiend-patron warlock's Dark One's Blessing feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, temporary-hit-points, duration

What is the duration of the temporary hit points granted by the Fiend-patron warlock's Dark One's Blessing feature?

Comment: Related: [How do you get temporary hit points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137121/how-do-you-get-temporary-hit-points)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unless a feature tells you otherwise, they last until you take a long rest (or spend them)

Quoting from the [SRD](http://srd) :

> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they’re depleted or you finish a long rest.

Comment: Or replaced with another source of temporary hit points, because they don't stack. https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/867254585827532800

Answer (score 9):

## Until they have been used up or you've taken a long rest

PHB, 198:

> When you have temporary hit points and take damage, the temporary hit points are lost first, and any leftover damage carries over to your normal hit points...Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they’re depleted or you finish a long rest.