# How long does the temporary HP from the Circle of the Shepherd druid's Bear Spirit Totem last?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, temporary-hit-points, duration

The [Circle of the Shepherd druid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#CircleoftheShepherd)'s [Spirit Totem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#SpiritTotem-676) feature lets the druid summon a spirit that creates an aura with a certain effect. One option for the type of spirit is the Bear Spirit (XGtE, p. 23):

> ***Bear Spirit.*** The bear spirit grants you and your allies its might and endurance. Each creature of your choice in the aura when the spirit appears gains temporary hit points equal to 5 + your druid level. In addition, you and your allies gain advantage on Strength checks and Strength saving throws while in the aura.

The PHB ruling says that unless otherwise stated, [temporary HP](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) can last until the character that receives it takes a long rest. Now, I am planning to use the Bear Spirit before short or long rests to provide my team some temporary HP. My fear is that it might be too OP.

How long does the temporary HP from the Shepherd druid's Bear Spirit Totem last?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warlock's Dark One’s Blessing duration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110743/warlocks-dark-one-s-blessing-duration)

Comment: Are you essentially asking if your interpretation/guess (that the temp HP will last until the creature that receives it finishes a long rest) is correct?

Comment: Hello V2Blast, yes it is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the answers to the [linked question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110743/what-is-the-duration-of-the-temporary-hit-points-granted-by-the-fiend-patron-war), the rules for [temporary hit points](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints) state:

> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, they last until they’re depleted or you finish a long rest.

Since no duration is mentioned here you assume they last unless they are replaced by another spell, used up or the target takes a long rest.

This is all valid by RAW and you should not worry about it being too OP. It has been out for over a year now and no errata has been published. Just have fun with it.

Comment: I think the final paragraph talking about this strategy's strength could use to address the trade-off the questioner will see between getting the THP immediately and not having the aura effect when they're needed.